# How to get Time Machine disk to backup itself?

Tags: backup, time-machine, partition

How to get Time Machine disk to backup itself (ie, non-`Backups.backupdb` on the Time Machine disk)?

Specifically: I moved my `/Users` folder [to a separate parition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55533/13179), a parition that also houses Time Machine backups (for my boot-SSD parition in `/Users/Backups.backupdb`).  I also want to Time-Machine backup the /Users/ folders, but Time Machine won't (thus far) let me backup folders/files on the same disk where the Time-Machines backups are stored.

From one standbpoint, it makes sense to keep physically-different disks.  (I employ multiple Time-Machine disks for this purpose, including for system above.)  However, most backup needs are not due to physical-drive failure, but a "logical/soft" fault (usually me accidently deleting files), and as such, enabling the backups above would prove quite valuable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to recreate something Time Machine already does via its "Local Snapshots" feature (see [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21435/how-do-local-timemachine-backups-work-exactly) for info).  Basically, all you need to do is configure your Mac to back up to an external drive, and then whenever that drive isn't available it'll make local snapshots instead (as long as there's disk space available).

Comment: Need "local shapshots" to enable backups of /Users/<homedirs> to /Users/Backups.backupdb.  All with external drive continually plugged in.  (And it's not an external drive, it's a 2nd drive in my Hackintosh.)  Can something support this?