# Time Machine: Local Snapshots and Backup while on Battery

Tags: time-machine

I like the idea of local Snapshots for having the possibility to restore accidentally deleted or changed files. My question is, when unchecking "Backup while on Battery Power" is Time Machine still creating those Snapshots?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the switch "Backup while on Battery Power" is for you to choose if to continue the time machine backup while on battery or NOT.

The reason is to allow you to preserve battery power by unchecking it, but it will no longer create Snapshots.

Comment: So, I can't disable the Backups to the external drive while on battery but keep the snapshot-feature on?

Comment: AFIK you can not.

Comment: read this, it might help http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/18549/46541